# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Tags: php, mysql, android, recyclerview

`1.`Tengo el siguiente codigo para tomar fotos y mostrarlas en un recyclerview con forma de gridview y lo que quiero es que al momento de dar en el boton agregar las imagenes se almacenen en el servidor y el puro nombre de la foto en mysql. Tambien tengo el problema que cuando tomo las fotos las muestra en horizontal apesar de que las tome en vertical.

Ya investigue y solo encuentro de que manera cargar fotografias pero que son seleccionadas desde galeria y lo quise implementar con mi codigo pero ya no me cargaban las fotos en el recycler view.

`2.`Tambien el textview que se muestra con nombre de count ahi quiero mostrar el numero de fotos que van mediante el metodo `size()` de mi adapter el unico problema es que si lo mando a llamar en un textview que esta fuera del recyclerview me falla la aplicacion pero si pongo un textview en el recycler me muestra la cantidad pero en ves de uno solo me muestra los textview de los item que detecta como puedo solucionar eso.

Imagen con el metodo `size()` dentro del recyclerview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando llamo el metodo en un textview fuera del recycler me muestra el siguiente error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

FotoAdapter

```
public class FotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FotoAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Bitmap> lista;
    private Context context;

    public FotoAdapter(List<Bitmap> lista, Context context) {
        this.lista = lista;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_foto,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bitmap bit=lista.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bit);
        holder.txcou.setText(lista.size() + "/13");
        holder.txsize.setText(lista.size() + "/13");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView image;
        TextView txcou,txsize;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
            txsize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.countImg);
        }
    }
}
```

GalleryFragment

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;
    private RecyclerView listaFotos;
    private FotoAdapter adapter;

    private List<Bitmap> fotos =  new ArrayList<>();

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        listaFotos=binding.listaFotos;
        adapter=new FotoAdapter(fotos, getContext());
        listaFotos.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4));
        listaFotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton btn=binding.fotografiar;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hacerFoto();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    private File archivo;
    private void hacerFoto() {
        try {
            Intent i =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            archivo = crearFichero();
            Uri foto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.rampasimage.fileprovider", archivo);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, foto);

            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode==1){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
                fotos.add(image);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }else {

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private File crearFichero() throws IOException {
        String pre="foto_";
        File directorio=getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File img = File.createTempFile(pre + UUID.randomUUID().toString(),".jpg", directorio);
        return img;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

fragment_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista_fotos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style_borde_edittext"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fotografiar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtrailer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Caja"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtipo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Tipo Embarque"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="count"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Agregar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lista_fotos" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_foto.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foto"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="227dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Count" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el layout `item_foto.xml` no se encuentra el TextView con id `size`, debes asegurar que los elementos de los cuales tratas de obtener la referencia existe

```
  ...
  ...
  public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto); //* Obtiene referencia.
            txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size); //* Obtiene referencia.
            txsize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.countImg); //* Obtiene referencia.
        }
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Si existen el id size es que se repite en el recycler_view como `6/13` ahi si me muestra el valor del metodo `size`, el problema es el textview que dice `count` tiene id `countImg` que esta declarado en `fragment_gallery` ya anexe los xml

Comment: Si, agregalos a el layout item_foto.xml y no tendrás el error.

Comment: Pero si lo agrego en el item_foto.xml se repetiria y solo quiero que sevea un solo textview que en este caso es el que esta fuera del recycler view identificado como Count ahi quiero que me muestre cuantas fotos llevo de las 13 requeridas